# Swift IOS: Call Specific function of UIviewController when open app from notification

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, nsnotificationcenter

I want to call `onDidReceiveNotification` function when the application is open using tap on the notification. (`ViewController` is first view controller, root view controller)

It is working fine when the application is open or in the background, But when application is not open or in background (not in memory) and tap to open application at that time `onDidReceiveNotification` function is not call,

What should I do to call `onDidReceiveNotification` function when the app is open using tap on push notification

**ViewController.swift**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .didReceiveAlert, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.onDidReceiveNotification(_:)), name: .didReceiveAlert, object: nil)
    }

@objc func onDidReceiveNotification(_ notification:Notification) {
        print("Received Notification")
    }
}
```

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {            
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .didReceiveAlert, object: nil)       
}
```

Comment: I think this is the expected behaviour and in case the app is closed, you need to check the `launchOptions` from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in appdelegate to get the received notification details.

Comment: didReceiveRemoteNotification is call when app is closed and open using notification

Comment: check remote notification on app launch by `let remoteNotif = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? [String: Any]`

Comment: Ok for example i have checked in launchOptions, i know app is open using notification, But then after how could call my function "onDidReceiveNotification" in viewcontroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When app is open or in background at that time called `NotificationCenter.defalut.post` and when app is terminated/closed and open using notification at that time get the instance and call menually `onDidReceiveAlert` function, See the following code.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    if application.applicationState == .background || application.applicationState == .active {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .didReceiveAlert, object: nil)
    }else {
        let nav = window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
        let mainVC = nav.viewControllers.first as! ViewController
        mainVC.onDidReceiveAlert(nil)
    }
}
```

OR Just get `ViewController` instance from  `UINavigationController` stack and call directly the function of `ViewController` (Notification Observer not reqired)

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    let nav = window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
    let mainVC = nav.viewControllers.first as! ViewController
    mainVC.onDidReceiveAlert(nil)       
}
```

Create function with an optional parameter, use the following code.

```
@objc func onDidReceiveAlert(_ notification:Notification? = nil) {
    print("Received Notification")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below code

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    if let remoteNotif = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? [String: Any] {
         //call your notification method from here
         NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .didReceiveAlert, object: nil)  
    }
}
```

hope you just need to call the `didReceiveAlert` notification in all case

Answer (score 0):

When the app in the inactive state and user tap on a notification. in that situation only single option to manage notification.

Try this

Create a variable in global class so you can access it from anywhere.

**Ex** Create variable in **AppDelegate**

```
var isNotificationTap : Bool = false
```

After that check `launchOptions` and if `launchOptions` available then set Flag

```
if launchOptions != nil {
    if let userInfo = launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? [String : AnyObject] {
        if let dic = userInfo["body"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
            if let pushType = dic["push_type"] as? String {
                //Set Flag or any key in global file to identify that you tap on notification
                self.isNotifcaionTap = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then simply check a flag in ViewController.

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if self.isNotificationTap {

            print("Received Notification")
            //You can work with your notificaiton in inActive state
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't want to use the global variable, it is a very low-quality method, Is there any other approach

Comment: the main problem with the inactive state of push notification is we have only option to track inactive notification tap on didFinishLauching launch options and we don't have rootViewController to manage notification flow. so we only have the option to set key or flag to manage.

Answer (score -1):

In AppDelegate check if you get the payload in didReceiveRemoteNotification. From there you can write the code to push to particular page.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)
    pushToPage(data: userInfo)
}

func pushToPage(data:[AnyHashable : Any]){
    print("Push notification received: \(data)")
    if let aps = data["aps"] as? NSDictionary {
        print(aps)
    }
}
```